# set ToolTip for dropdownlist inside gridview from query from database asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, tooltip

I am writing asp.net project in C# and I have a litle problem.

I have a dropdownlist inside gridview and both of them initially is filled from one database but different tables(different select queries).

I want to set ToolTip for dropdownlist from query which is used to fill gridview(DataTable1) by following code:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="choose supervisor"  ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                 <ItemTemplate>                
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"                 
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged"
 ToolTip =<%#((DataSet1.DataTable1Row)(((DataRowView)Container.DataItem).Row)).p_id %>>
                       </asp:DropDownList>
                  </ItemTemplate>                
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

but when I try run the project I get the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

If I try set Tooltip manually, for example:

```
ToolTip = "abc"
```

the project runs without any problem.

Does someone know how to set tooltip for dropdownlist from database query?
Thanks.

Comment: The Container.DataItem is not always available. Why not Eval("p_id")?

Comment: if I try ToolTip = <%#Eval("p_id")%> I get an error: Methods of data binding, for example, Eval (), XPath (), and Bind (), can be used only in the context of the bound control to data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do that from GridView's [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event which is triggered for every `GridViewRow` but only when the `GridView` gets databound.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (GridView)sender;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        DataSet ds = drv.Row.Table.DataSet;
        // i'm not 100% sure what you need here, for example:
        DropDownList1.ToolTip = drv.Row.Field<int>("p_id").ToString();
    }
}
```

This is much more readable and easier to maintain and debug.

Comment: I tried this, but didn't get result. I want to set tooltip in order to get it inside .cs code by following function:                protected void ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            string p_id = (sender as DropDownList).ToolTip;
            Response.Write("dropdownlist: " + p_id);             
            
        }

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov: Can you specify _"I tried this, but didn't get result"_. Have you tried exact code above and got errors? If that's  true, what kind of errors, compiler or runtime errrors and what exact type of errors? Have you used the debuger to see what happens, what is the type of `e.Row.DataItem` for example?